# watir webdriver / non visible element / display:none!important

Tags: css, watir-webdriver, invisible

I have a problem with a non visible element with watir webdriver

In the html code the word is not visible :

```
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-binding">ZT0</td>
```

the css I found

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .hidden-xs{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .hidden-sm{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

I think the `display:none` don't allow the bot to read it...

when I wrote in my script .rb :

```
puts browser.tbody(:index, 3).tr(:index, 0).td(:index => 3, ).text
```

It gave me a blank request although I saw ZTO on my screen!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS classes say that the `td` element will not be displayed when the browser width is less than 991px. You may need to increase the browser width to be larger than this. Try maximizing the browser first:

```
browser.window.maximize
puts browser.tbody(:index, 3).tr(:index, 0).td(:index => 3, ).text
```

If you are not trying to test the responsive design, you could use `inner_html` to get the text. It will return the contents regardless of the browser width.

```
puts browser.tbody(:index, 3).tr(:index, 0).td(:index => 3, ).inner_html
#=> "Z10"
```